# Using jQuery to trigger CSS shake animation, works every OTHER time ... why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shake

I have a rather simple fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7aotzqmL/2/ that is supposed to shake a div with CSS animation upon clicking a link. It works, but only every other time (every second time). I'm stumped - can anybody help?

Other answers I've looked at mentioned how when using onmouseover you also need to attach onmouseout... but this is just a click so I'm not sure that's relevant. I just want the div to shake on every click rather than every other.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7aotzqmL/2/

CSS code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function(ev) {
    $('div').toggleClass('shaker');
    ev.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
div.shaker {
  animation: shake 0.3s;
  /* When the animation is finished, start again */
  animation-iteration-count: 1; //single shake 
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">asd</a>
<div>shake</div>
```

Comment: it seems to me that the problem is that my div's class "shaker" is removed by the 2nd click, since that's the 2nd call to toggleClass. This would explain working every 2nd time. However, when I add a check before calling toggleClass like: `if ($('div').hasClass('shaker')) { $('div').removeClass('shaker'); }` it still doesn't work. Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this will work

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(ev){

       $('div').addClass('shaker'); 

       setTimeout(function(){

       $('div').removeClass('shaker'); 
       },300);
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Below code is removing class on even time click, and you animation working on adding class

```
$('div').toggleClass('shaker');
```

in above solution, div class will be removed after 0.3secs animation, it will add 'shaker' class every time you click and animation will happen

Comment: thank you, I had quite literally just come up with the same solution myself and was about to delete the question when I saw it had already been answered. For anyone else having the same problem, this solution works very well! It seems that since some of these functions are non-blocking, you need to use setTimeout, in this case the value of 300 corresponds to the fact that the animation is defined as 0.3s. If you set the value of the argument to setTimeout() to less than 300, you will not be able to see the animation fully complete.

Comment: The method I posted in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56647941/1994081) gets around that issue by removing the class once the animation completes. You can change the animation length as much as you like without also having to update a timeout. I personally avoid using timeouts as much as possible as they are so fragile and prone to creating hard to discover bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You are toggling the class so the first click adds it and the second removes it. Instead you could add the class on click and set a single use event listener to listen for the animation end and then remove the class.

```js
$(function() {
  const div = $('.container')
  $('a').click(function(ev) {
    div.addClass('shaker')
    div.one('animationend', () => {
      div.removeClass('shaker')
    })
    ev.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.container.shaker {
  /* Start the shake animation and make the animation last for 0.5 seconds */
  animation: shake 0.3s;
  /* When the animation is finished, start again */
  animation-iteration-count: 1; //single shake 
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">asd</a>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, you're TOGGLING the class. so one click means "add" the next one means "remove". Also, "preventdefault" should appear first in order to prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag before you try to add or remove classes.

```
    $(function(){
          $('a').click(function(ev){
              ev.preventDefault();
              $('div').addClass('shaker'); 
              setTimeout(()=> {
                  $('div').removeClass('shaker');
              },300)
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$('a').click(function(ev){
  $('div').addClass('shaker'); 
   setTimeout(()=>{
   $('div').removeClass('shaker');
   },300)
    ev.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Use the above code. You were removing the **shaker** class alternatively.